# How to set Element as ReadOnly by clicking outside the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `<input>` element set to `readonly` by default:

```
<input readonly id="uniqueId" type="text" ondblclick="onDoubleClick(this.id)">
```

If the user double-clicks this element it will be set to editable with:

```
function onDoubleClick(id){
    var element = $('#'+id);
    if (element.prop('readonly')==true) { element.prop('readonly', false);}
    else { element.prop('readonly', true); }
```

Apparently this `<input>` element will stay editable up until the user double clicks it again. I wonder if I could link a mouse `click` that happens outside of the `<input>` element to turn it into readonly again. How to achieve it?

Comment: Are you trying to specifically do this if there is a click event? What about if they tab out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could rely on the `blur` event to take action when it loses focus

```js
function onDoubleClick(elem) {
  console.log('toggling readonly property');
  var element = $(elem);
  element.prop('readonly', !element.prop('readonly')); // toggle
}

function lostFocus(elem) {
  console.log('lostFocust');
  var element = $(elem);
  element.prop('readonly', true);
}
```

```css
input {
  background-color: white;
}
input[readonly] {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input readonly id="uniqueId" type="text"  ondblclick="onDoubleClick(this)" onblur="lostFocus(this)">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make any clicks on the document make the element readonly.

```js
function onDoubleClick(id) {
  var element = $('#' + id);
  if (element.prop('readonly') == true) {
    element.prop('readonly', false);
  } else {
    element.prop('readonly', true);
  }
}

function inputClicked(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}

$(document).click(function() {
  $('#uniqueId').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

```css
input[readonly] {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly id="uniqueId" type="text" onclick="inputClicked(event)" ondblclick="onDoubleClick(this.id)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches which I suggest

**Method 1** - Using `one`

Add this inside your current function

```
$('html').one('click',function() {
    $("#uniqueId").prop('readonly', true); 
  });
```

Explanation: when ever you double click and make the input editable The above script will attach `one` click event to HTML which makes the input read-only. This event works only once as we have used `one`.

So technically when ever you make the input editable a new event is attached which will make input read-only on further click.

**Method 2** - Checking if the click was outside the element

Add this into your script.

```
$('html').on('click',function(e){
  if(!$(event.target).is('#uniqueId'))
  {
    $("#uniqueId").prop('readonly', true); 
  }   
});
```

Explanation: when ever there is a click on you HTML you will check if the click was on the input, If not then make it readonly.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a `blur` event to the input box, so it will make field readonly even if user hits TAB and moves out of field.

```js
$("input").on("blur", function() {
  $(this).prop('readonly', true);
})

function onDoubleClick(id) {
  var element = $('#' + id);
  if (element.prop('readonly') == true) {
    element.prop('readonly', false);
  } else {
    element.prop('readonly', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly id="uniqueId" type="text" ondblclick="onDoubleClick(this.id)">
```

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery needed here since we already have access to the element when using the `ondblclick` handler, and you can add a function to the `onfocusout` or `onblur` event handler of your element:

```
<input readonly id="uniqueId" type="text" ondblclick="onDoubleClick(this)" onfocusout="onFocusOut(this)">

<script>
  function onDoubleClick(element){
    element.readOnly = !element.readOnly;
  }

  function onFocusOut(element) {
    element.readOnly = true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as the `ondblclick` attribute you can use the `onblur` attribute of the `input` element. It will run that function once that element gets blurred (out of focus).

```js
function onDoubleClick(el) {
  var element = $(el);
  if (element.prop('readonly')==true) {
    element.prop('readonly', false);
  } else {
    element.prop('readonly', true); 
  } 
}
function onBlur(el) {
  $(el).prop('readonly', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly id="uniqueId" type="text" ondblclick="onDoubleClick(this)" onblur="onBlur(this)">
```